# Can a working Tomcat 6 webapp be turned into a usable .war file?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, packaging, web-applications

Problem: I have a working webapp on a FreeBSD 8.1 Tomcat 6 test server that I need to move to a production system. The developer who last touched it (and had root on that server) has moved on and isn't helpful. The running app seems to have been deployed from a CVS server that is now unavailable.

My thinking is that I would like to find a way to wrap the working webapp into a proper .war so that I can deploy it on a pristine host and (after testing) send the existing system to a very deep bitbucket. But I'm not having luck finding a way to do that.

I'm a sysadmin not a developer and don't work much with Tomcat systems so I may be (likely am) overlooking something blindingly simple. I gather that I may be able to just tar up the deployed directory and untar it on the new machine, but I have a nagging feeling that there are pitfalls in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jar utility that comes with java.

cd into the webapp folder and run the following:

`jar cvf ../mywebapp.war *`

Comment: Also: I'm still standing up the new host so I can't say "this worked," but it is very helpful to know that a warfile (warball?) is a jarfile of the webapp with no top-level directory.

Comment: Worked like a dream. Dropped the .war in the webapps directory on a new system and Tomcat unpacked it without complaint.